# Swift recursive enums

Tags: swift, recursion, enums

I'm trying to learn more about recursive enums.

Here's my code:

```
enum Operation {
    case Unary((Double) -> Double)
    case Binary((Double, Double) -> Double)

    indirect case Combined(Operation, Operation)
}

let x = 7.0
let y = 9.0
let z = x + y

let plus = Operation.Binary{$0 + $1}
let squareRoot = Operation.Unary{sqrt($0)}

let combined = Operation.Combined(plus, squareRoot)

switch combined {
    case let .Unary(value):
        value(z)
    case let .Binary(function):
        function(x, y)
    case let .Combined(mix): 
        mix(plus, squareRoot)
}
```

How can I perform `plus` and then `squareRoot` operation one after another?

I keep getting this error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type (Operation, Operation)

Comment: I can not understand, what is the intent behind `.Combined`?  I.e. what do you expect to happen with `.Combined(plus, squareRoot)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.Unary` and `.Binary` you are doing it right. You are retrieving the functions and executing them.

With `.Combined` however, you are retrieving a tuple of operations and using it as if it were a function. What you should do, is to retrieve the functions within the tuple and execute them.

Instead of your switch you could use a recursive function, like this:

```
func handleOperation(operation: Operation) {
    switch operation {
    case let .Unary(value): value(z)
    case let .Binary(function): function(x, y)
    case let .Combined(op1, op2): [op1, op2].map(handleOperation)
    }
}
```

Comment: case let .Combined(op1, op2): [op1, op2].map {handleOperation($0)}

Here .map passes each of [op1, op2] array element into closure as an argument?

Comment: @KK7, exactly, it is the same as `handleOperation(op1); handleOperation(op2) `

Comment: handleOperation already has the same signiture as the closure expected in `map`. You can just do: `...map(handleOperation)`